# why pop up or tool tip not display on icon click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

![enter image description here][1]I am trying to show tooltip on icon (star button on each row).But I don't know why it display without any event.i want to display tooltip or popup when user click on star icon .I make a custom directive but it is not working .it already display .it should show on star icon ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/OYiawflIBnpJ1PKx02LG?p=preview

```
app.directive('popUpCheck', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template :"<ul class='list-group'>"
  +"<li class='list-group-item'>Edit</li>"
  +"<li class='list-group-item'>Delete</li>"
  +"<li class='list-group-item'>copy</li>"

+"</ul>",
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            scope.label = attrs.popoverLabel;
            $(el).popover({
                trigger: 'click',
                html: true,
                placement: 'right'
            });
        }
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to show popover is angular js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134859/how-to-show-popover-is-angular-js)

Comment: but there is no solution in thread..do you have any solution

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos do you have any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you haven't included jQuery, which is essential in what you've tried to do.

Secondly, you've included [AngularUI's Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) - which consists of directives which already does what you want to do. If you want to be able to access Bootstrap methods such as `.popover()` on a `jQuery` object you're gonna have to include the regular Twitter Bootstrap script instead (with appropriate plugins).

Thirdly, why would you even do this in your JavaScript when you're using Angular - what you've done is what AngularJS does *not* want you to do.

Fourthly, your HTML is kinda messed up, and I couldn't be arsed to fix it up - but here's my "fix" to what you're trying to do (I think). http://plnkr.co/edit/gwkeDp5iqzyLIbFHCbuz?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for answering ..can we show "edit",copy,delete option using directive

Comment: I assume you mean show them as in show them when you click the star, or something? Checkout *Dropdown* section [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Comment: instead  of show that message  "his is your AngularUI popover directive"..can we show three "li" element

Comment: give me second I will give a image what I want

Comment: please check my update..can we show like this ..as I have in image ..I have 3 li having some value "edit",copy,"delete".on icon click

Comment: do you have any idea about that ..how i will achieve this

Comment: Yeah. I'd use any of the following for printing the 3 dots - FontAwesome/Glyphicons/Icomoon/Fontello.

For the dropdown menu I'd take a look at **Dropdowns** at [AngularUI's Bootstrap page](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), which I linked to earlier.

Comment: I don't want 3 dot's ..I want popover on star like as image.I think this is not dropdown .this is tooltio or pop over in angular UI bootstrap

Comment: ?. You already know everything you need to know to get started. I don't work for you :)